# Assert or infer a value is non-null

Tags: typescript, types

I have a function that I am using to clean null values out of array data that it is passed. With an optional transform function to change the array elements into some arbitrary shape you need. It looks like this

```
export const getValidItems = <TItem, TReturn>(
  items: Maybe<TItem>[],
  transform?: (item: TItem) => TReturn
) => {
  const validItems: (TItem | TReturn)[] = [];
  items.forEach((item) => {
    if (item) {
      const outputItem = transform ? transform(item) : item;
      if (outputItem) {
        validItems.push(outputItem);
      }
    }
  });
  return validItems;
};
```

Here is my usage of this function:

`const nodes = getValidItems(edges, ({ node }) => node);`

Even though I am checking for non-null values in `getValidItems`, when I try to map over my `nodes` variable, typescript gives me a warning that `Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'`

Previously I had this logic in another method, but I abstracted it out to this helper function. When the `if (item)` and `if (outputItem)` checks where in that method, TS could correctly identify that the values were non-null. however when I moved it to the `getValidItems` helper, the errors started appearing.

for some context, here is the function before I created the helper

```
export const getNodes = <TNode>(data?: { edges?: { node?: TNode | null }[] | null }) => {
  const { edges } = data || {};
  if (!edges) {
    return [];
  }

  const validNodes: TNode[] = [];
  edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    if (node) {
      validNodes.push(node);
    }
  });
  return validNodes;
};
```

and here is the function after I created the helper:

```
export const getNodes = <TNode>(data?: { edges?: { node?: TNode | null }[] | null }) => {
  const { edges } = data || {};
  if (!edges) {
    return [];
  }

  const nodes = getValidItems(edges, ({ node }) => node);
  return nodes
};
```

In the new `getNodes` typescript seems unable to infer that `nodes` is `(typeof node)[]`, and that the items in the array are not null

Is there away to assert that the output of my method doesn't contain null or undefined, or is there a different way to write the method so typescript can infer this information and the return type of `transform`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple things going on here.

The first is that you are returning `(TItem | TReturn)[]` which is an array of items where each item in the array could be TItem or TReturn.

You can see that this complicates the type of nodes to be: `({ node?: TNode | null | undefined } | TNode | null | undefined)[]`. This is because - by the types - every item in the array could be either `typeof edges[0]` or the return type of your transform function (which is `TNode | null | undefined`). When iterating over this array, you would have to check every item to see if it's the return type or the type of one of the edges.

That's not actually accurate to your method, which actually returns `TItem[] | TReturn[]`, or in English "Either an array of TItems or an array of TReturns". But we can narrow this further to say that it's `TItems[]` if no optional transform function is provided, and if one *is* provided, then it's an array of the return type of that function.

This can be more accurately represented with function overloading like so:

```
export function getValidItems<TItem>(items: Maybe<TItem>[]): TItem[]
export function getValidItems<TItem, TReturn>(items: Maybe<TItem>[], transform: (item: TItem) => TReturn): TReturn[]
export function getValidItems<TItem, TReturn>(items: Maybe<TItem>[], transform?: (item: TItem) => TReturn): TItem[] | TReturn[] {
  const validItems: (TItem | TReturn)[] = [];
  items.forEach((item) => {
    if (item) {
      const outputItem = transform ? transform(item) : item;
      if (outputItem) {
        validItems.push(outputItem);
      }
    }
  });
  return validItems as TItem[] | TReturn[];
};
```

We've now narrowed down the type of `nodes` considerably to be `(TNode | null | undefined)[]` This is accurately inferring the return type of the transform function, which returns the node (which you've declared as type `TNode | null`.

So there is one more thing the `getValidItems()` function is doing that is not currently reflected in the types. It is checking that the result of `transform()` is truthy or it will be filtered out. To type this we need to assert that the resulting array is not an array of `TReturn`s, it's an array of non-null `TReturn`s. We can do this with the built in `NonNullable<T>` helper type like so:

```
export function getValidItems<TItem>(items: Maybe<TItem>[]): TItem[]
export function getValidItems<TItem, TReturn>(items: Maybe<TItem>[], transform: (item: TItem) => TReturn): NonNullable<TReturn>[]
export function getValidItems<TItem, TReturn>(items: Maybe<TItem>[], transform?: (item: TItem) => TReturn): TItem[] | TReturn[] {
  const validItems: (TItem | TReturn)[] = [];
  items.forEach((item) => {
    if (item) {
      const outputItem = transform ? transform(item) : item;
      if (outputItem) {
        validItems.push(outputItem);
      }
    }
  });
  return validItems as TItem[] | TReturn[];
};
```

Now if you iterate over `nodes` you can access properties without typescript warning that it could be `null` or `undefined`.

You can see this working in the playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhAPAFQHxQLxTVAHygDsBXAG3MKlOIBMIAzAS2IjoG4AoLiADzAB7AE7AojWgGNgzQcSgBzCMABqccszoBJYBAC2AZ3Q79GABTNdhgFywEyY1YwBtALoBKW2hN63vASJiEsTSsvJKquqaPkbeVgA0eABKyqTCxOaW%20ga28EiocaZuicDCcMQGjCJ6thZWXj7uOFhoKcBpxJ5QAHJy3RTkcIjkBW0dLq7%20QqLiUjJyispqGtpWsT6JranpmWu59gU%20EyVlFVXCegD8tVk1eI3NydudDVZu1Fvt6e8A3lxQUEkcgMYgAblFVtlaoU9B8xul3O9cG5uADbgYAHTnACicEkAAszHV9E1sFg-gC0YwoMS9E0KZSAUCKmJBKRgGB2T4cFBSuVKtUoJdeacBRdaU1bLdUYyoMxqWY2RyuVZ6f9ZQDwSsYhjOQZCUrOcBGjLGQBfdUAi1W9wy4TPKBa6JrKBwAz3N6uOHPFFcM3cHj8aZiZkgxbAXoMd24dCR6D8XT0d0-cSCQS2EHCVgKDhQM3mOhwYBwa5QFPsJQGUsp4iCBiltBx6hkSh595EFtUM2k8nq0Nict0St5nmF4uEIg-f3q%20U0gCEFYgBjVjPtX3kvqtPCZwLEtajPIiy2d2TMi4MiTMNbr0G7j33EFt25IN8xOLxhIfjwZO4qghGGLkIIChmA%20WJpk%20NoBgCa4dC%20UZ%20hwQA).